# Why do I get EVariantTypeCastError exception when calling Locate?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

This line of code:

```
Q.Locate('HS_VID', VarArrayOf([hsVid]), []);
```

gives me this error:

> Project Test.exe raised exception class EVariantTypeCasterror with message 'Could not convert variant of type (OleStr)".

the variables are declared as follows:

```
var
  Q: TADOQuery;
  hsVid: string;
```

`Q` is indexed on the `HS_VID` field. The SQL for `Q` is:

```
Q.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM HS_CONTSILO ORDER BY HS_VID');
```

Does anyone what could be wrong with that line?

Comment: You have to pass only single value, not an array when you're going to filter by a single field.